# Python: Slow for Loop

Tags: python, json, api, oracle-sqldeveloper, atom-editor

It is taking much more time to execute the script than expected. For just 1250 records, it is taking 20 plus minutes to loop and insert into the table.
Please let us know if this is normal

Below are the 11 columns fetched from API(JSON) and loading each row into the table(oracle).

script :

```
auth_values = (user, passwd)
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

for data in json_data['result']:
        branchFullName = data['full_name']
        branchNum = data['u_branch_id']
        branchName = data['u_branch_name']
        sysId= data['sys_id']
        sys_updated_on = data['sys_updated_on']
        sys_created_on = data['sys_created_on']
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+PrestageTable+"(BRANCH_FULL_NAME, 
        BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH_NAME,SYS_ID,SYS_CREATED_ON,SYS_UPDATED_ON) VALUES 
        (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)", 
    (branchFullName,branchNum,branchName,sysId,sys_updated_on,sys_created_on))
        con.commit()
```

Is there way to use indexing, or any suggestions.

```
Updated:
    insert_data = []
    for data in json_data['result']:
        branchFullName = data['full_name']
        branchNum = data['u_branch_id']
        branchName = data['u_branch_name']
        sysId= data['sys_id']
        sys_updated_on = data['sys_updated_on']
        sys_created_on = data['sys_created_on']
        insert_data.append(
        (branchFullName, branchNum, branchName, sysId, sys_updated_on, sys_created_on)
        )

        args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in insert_data)
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {PrestageTable} VALUES " + args_str)
    con.commit()
```

Added the JSON file.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "country": {
                "link": "https://xyz.service-now.com/api/now/table/core_country/ebc0713f4",
                "value": "9d38b7111b121100763d91eebc0713f4"
            },
            "parent": "",
            "city": "trgtt",
            "latitude": "",
            "sys_updated_on": "2019-10-04 16:44:21",
            "type": "",
            "sys_class_name": "u_branch",
            "sys_id": "565666",
            "u_daily_limit": "0",
            "sys_updated_by": "SYffffLVPAU",
            "u_branch_name": "tyfhh",
            "stock_room": "false",
            "street": "KM 66 jhhhj jhg jhhhh - PORTÃO 01 - SALA DG",
            "sys_created_on": "2019-07-25 16:26:18",
            "contact": "",
            "phone_territory": "",
            "u_active": "true",
            "company": "",
            "lat_long_error": "",
            "u_branch_id": "vfg",
            "state": "",
            "consumer": "",
            "sys_created_by": "gghhh",
            "longitude": "",
            "u_region": "REGIONAL 1",
            "zip": "",
            "u_code": "",
            "u_dmm": "false",
            "sys_mod_count": "1",
            "sys_tags": "",
            "time_zone": "",
            "full_name": "VCP - yghg",
            "fax_phone": "",
            "phone": "09-4321-3920",
            "u_ddr": "false",
            "name": "VCP - gfghj",
            "u_cutoff_time": "",
            "coordinates_retrieved_on": "",
            "u_schedule": "",
            "account": "",
            "primary": "false"
        },
        {
            "country": {
                "link": "https://xyz.service-now.com/api/now/table/core_country/1eebc0713f4",
                "value": "fgddddfghh"
            },
            "parent": "",
            "city": "rerdr BRAZ",
            "latitude": "",
            "sys_updated_on": "2019-10-04 16:44:21",
            "type": "",
            "sys_class_name": "u_branch",
            "sys_id": "5644",
            "u_daily_limit": "0",
            "sys_updated_by": "gg",
            "u_branch_name": "hff BRAS",
            "stock_room": "false",
            "street": "302B RUA gffg ELIAS",
            "sys_created_on": "2019-07-25 16:26:19",
            "contact": "",
            "phone_territory": "",
            "u_active": "true",
            "company": "",
            "lat_long_error": "",
            "u_branch_id": "frg",
            "state": "",
            "consumer": "",
            "sys_created_by": "gtft",
            "longitude": "",
            "u_region": "REGIO 2",
            "zip": "",
            "u_code": "",
            "u_dmm": "false",
            "sys_mod_count": "1",
            "sys_tags": "",
            "time_zone": "",
            "full_name": "WBR - yyjh BRAS",
            "fax_phone": "",
            "phone": "04-352-160",
            "u_ddr": "false",
            "name": "dfee - Wdd BRdS",
            "u_cutoff_time": "",
            "coordinates_retrieved_on": "",
            "u_schedule": "",
            "account": "",
            "primary": "false"
        }     ]
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the database insert code, that's probably where the delay is. Try using `executemany()` to do all the inserts at once instead of a separate call for each.

Comment: The slow part is presumably loading the data into oracle, which you haven't shown us...

Comment: This is more of a code review question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW, you can use `response.json()` to load the JSON in one step.

Comment: Looping over 1250 isn't a problem. But if you insert into a database each time, that could be very slow. Try combining your insertions into one query and do it with one insert.

Comment: Updated the question @YevhenKuzmovych

Comment: Tried it but, getting an error while inserting

Comment: I have tried executemany() but getting the error : code: cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO "+PrestageTable+"(BRANCH_FULL_NAME, BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH_NAME,SYS_ID,SYS_CREATED_ON,SYS_UPDATED_ON) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)", (branchFullName,branchNum,branchName,sysId,sys_updated_on,sys_created_on))
 @Barmar

Comment: You didn't say what the actual error is.

Comment: it just gives "error while inserting records into table". Also, i have added the json file for refrence. @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said you should insert multiple rows at once and do it once.

Try this:

```
insert_data = []
for data in json_data['result']:
    ... # branchFullName, branchNum, etc. variables
    inser_data.append(
        (branchFullName, branchNum, branchName, sysId, sys_updated_on, sys_created_on)
    )

args_str = ','.join(cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in insert_data)
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {PrestageTable} VALUES " + args_str) 
con.commit()
```

Note that the `execute` is outside the loop.

Comment: Getting error while inserting the records.Please review the latest code updated in question.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it just gives "error while inserting records into table". Also, i have added the json file for refrence.

Comment: Can you show an example of data in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cursor.executemany()` to insert all the rows at once. This requires that you create a 2-dimensional list of parameters for all the rows.

```
params = []
for data in json_data['result']:
    branchFullName = data['full_name']
    branchNum = data['u_branch_id']
    branchName = data['u_branch_name']
    sysId= data['sys_id']
    sys_updated_on = data['sys_updated_on']
    sys_created_on = data['sys_created_on']
    params.append((branchFullName,branchNum,branchName,sysId,sys_updated_on,sys_created_on)

cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO "+PrestageTable+"(BRANCH_FULL_NAME, 
        BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH_NAME,SYS_ID,SYS_CREATED_ON,SYS_UPDATED_ON) VALUES 
        (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)""", 
     params)
con.commit()
```

Comment: Error while inserting the records

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing in this code. This loop cannot take time to execute, so the problem is in retrievind the data, or inserting into oracle.
First of all i suggest to identify exaclty where is the problem, a tool of profiling like [perf_tool](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool) can help you a lot.It's impossible imagine what is going wrong here, but i think that after some inspections you will discover that the problem is in writing to db, so the solution probably is to do a bulk insert or work on indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes as per below and it is running faster now.
Code:

````
Updated:
    insert_data = []
    for data in json_data['result']:
        branchFullName = data['full_name']
        branchNum = data['u_branch_id']
        branchName = data['u_branch_name']
        sysId= data['sys_id']
        sys_updated_on = data['sys_updated_on']
        sys_created_on = data['sys_created_on']
        insert_data.append(
        (branchFullName, branchNum, branchName, sysId, sys_updated_on, sys_created_on)
        )

 
    cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {PrestageTable} VALUES " + insert_data)
    con.commit()```
````